# 3D view pie hotkey (or menu access) on Mac

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut, osx, pie-menu

I'm a Mac user and everybody knows some hotkeys are different from Linux/Windows to Mac, and with some effort I can find almost all of them, except 3D View Pie Menu, with tilde key.

I have a MacBook Pro with Tilde key on keyboard, but doesn't work, and I have an extra Mac keyboard and doesn't work too. The Mac keyboard is different and without some keys, so I bought a new windows keyboard just for that, but still not working. Is there anyone who knows how to access 3D View Pie Menu on a Mac using some hotkey or accessing from the menu on the top?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to locate the listing for the shortcut I believe you're making reference to. It wasn't easy to find. Once you know where it is located under the *Keymap* category within *User Preferences*, you can try to either target it using scripting, based on its **name** (In this case, VIEW3D_MT_view_pie), or, simply create an alternative keyboard shortcut, which will grant you access to the feature without use of any problematic default keys.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is the tilde key, but without the shift.  The key has the back tick and if the shift is used you get the tilde.  On the mac, just hit this key without using the shift.  In other words, it is the back tick key.